# How to add new List Action Menu item with JSOM/Javascript

Tags: sharepoint-online

does anybody know how can I add a new item to list actions menu with JSOM. I am able to add a custom action to a ribbon or to a list item menu (ECB), but I cannot find any reference how to add a new item to this menu.

[image]

So far, I have this code that I test in a console, and even though it returns a success, nothing is added

```
    var siteUrl = "https://mysharepoint"
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
var oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
this.oList = oWebsite.get_lists().getByTitle('List');
var collUserCustomAction = oList.get_userCustomActions();

var oUserCustomAction = collUserCustomAction.add();
oUserCustomAction.set_location('List.Actions.Menu');
oUserCustomAction.set_sequence(100);
oUserCustomAction.set_title('My First User Custom Action');
oUserCustomAction.set_url(siteUrl + '/_layouts/MyPage.aspx');
oUserCustomAction.update();

clientContext.load(oList, 'Title' ,'UserCustomActions');

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function(){alert("done")}, function(){alert("done")});
```

thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `location` is wrong. The correct `location` is *Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu* with `group` *ActionsMenu*.

Try this one here:

```
var siteUrl = "http://mysharepoint"
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);  
var oWeb = clientContext.get_web();  
var oList = oWeb.get_lists().getByTitle('List');  
var userCustomActionColl = oList.get_userCustomActions();  
var oUserCustomAction = userCustomActionColl.add();  
oUserCustomAction.set_location('Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu');  
oUserCustomAction.set_group('ActionsMenu');
oUserCustomAction.set_sequence(100); 
oUserCustomAction.set_title("My First User Custom Action");  
oUserCustomAction.set_url(siteUrl + '/_layouts/MyPage.aspx');   
oUserCustomAction.update();
clientContext.load(userCustomActionColl); 
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
    function(){
        console.log("success")
    }, 
    function(args){
        console.log('failure')
    }
);
```

The `sequence` property however doesn't seem to have any effect. That means that you can't specify where in the menu the new button will appear. Hence, it will be added to the bottom.

Comment: thank you, this works :) for all others, if you want to add an icon this action, use something like:
oUserCustomAction.set_imageUrl('url') ->

reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms460194.aspx